# Read each pixel/bit of a 1bit BMP using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba

I have been able to read a 24bits BMP file by getting the RGB value of each pixel, i.e. every 3bytes contributing to the color of a pixel. But to get the black/white value of each pixel in a 1bit BMP file, using VBA instead of other programming languages, the key is to read into a byte or each of the 8bits.

Assuming the 32bit boundary is handled by padding, is there any function already defined for reading each bit/pixel of such a 1bit BMP?

Comment: 24 bits = 3 bytes.  1 bit != 8 bits and 1 bit does not contain any "bytes".  Clarification please...

Comment: True, so I was asking if the programe can read "into" a byte. The problem with VBA opening a 1bit or 24bits BMP file is that the pixel data array is read in a per-byte manner. For a pixel in 24bits BMP, it is represented by 3 bytes; but for a pixel in a 1bit BMP, it is represented by 1 bit.

Comment: well I've never tried to do anything like that but I suppose it can probably be done. I would start with the module available from Chip Pearson's site: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BitsAndBytes.aspx  if you have specific problems *implementing* code, revise your Q to show what you have tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: thanks for the Pearson's quote. I did find some useful functions there. I was not aware of those conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim x() as Byte
```

An array of bytes.

x will be x(0) to x(1000000) so

```
For y = 0 to UBound(x) - 1
   'bit 0
    z=x(y) or &H1
   'bit 1
    z=x(y) or &H2
   'bit 2
    z=x(y) or &H4
   'bit 3
    z=x(y) or &H8
Next
```

Comment: To get the file off disk you need to use the adodb streamreader in binary mode. Using FSO will corrupt the data under some circumstances as windows translates bytes, which it thinks are characters, from one ANSI character codepoint to another. This is what text means in Windows, auto conversion of characters.

Comment: This is some sample code writing to disk. `Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2`

Comment: thanks a lot. I managed to store an array of bytes from the 1bit BMP using the ADODB.Stream. Then by checking the offset byte, I can locate the first byte of pixel data (represented by a decimal number, e.g. 85, then convert to binary, i.e. 01010101) and map to each pixel of the BMP file, e.g. black-white-black-white.....